# UNET (Multiplayer) calling [command] function twice

Tags: unity, multiplayer, unity-networking, unet

I am playing around with UNET but stuck into this weird problem/scenario while testing on same machine (unityEditor and buildRun to create "2 players/instances"

The problem is weird interaction of [Command] attribute and void OnStartLocalPlayer() when hosting the game in Editor's instance and in standalonePlayer instance

1. Basically, when I am host in editorInstance (host), the function associated with [Command] is triggered twice by the standaloneInstance (client)
2. When I am hosting in standaloneInstance (host), the line which calls the function associated with [Command] throws warning "Trying to send command for object without authority."
   But the function works as expected

I am spawning a PlayerObject from my NetworkLobbyManager and then that PlayerObject spawns its own pieces (sub-objects) using NetworkServer.Spawn(playerUnit);

Any help would be appreciated :( I like learning by trial and error but since 3 days I have not progressed or understood whats going on.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class playerManager : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public int playerID;
    public GameController GC;
    public int playerUnitID;
    public bool localPlayer;
    public bool serverPlayer;
    public bool clientPlayer;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        //Assign player unique ID as per order of joining
        if (!GC)
        {
            GC = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<GameController>();
            //playerID = this.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().connectionToClient.connectionId; connectionToClient is for serverOnly, connectionToServer is clientOnly
            playerID = (int)netId.Value;
            Debug.Log("(PM) Created GC in Start: " + playerID);
            //CmdCreatePlayerUnit(playerID);        //this gets called in OnStartLocalPlayer anyway(Trying to send command for object without authority)
        }
        localPlayer = isLocalPlayer;
        serverPlayer = isServer;
        clientPlayer = isClient;

        Debug.Log("Player: "+playerID+" isLocalPlayer: "+localPlayer+" and isServerPlayer: "+serverPlayer);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public override void OnStartLocalPlayer()
    {
        if (!GC)
        {
            GC = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<GameController>();
            //playerID = this.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().connectionToClient.connectionId; connectionToClient is for serverOnly, connectionToServer is clientOnly
            playerID = (int)netId.Value;
            Debug.Log("(PM) Created GC in OnStartLocalPlayer: " + playerID);
            CmdCreatePlayerUnit(playerID);
        }
        //Debug.Log("(PM) OnStartLocalPlayer: " + gameObject.name);
        Debug.Log("Player: " + playerID + " isLocalPlayer: " + localPlayer + " and isServerPlayer: " + serverPlayer);
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdCreatePlayerUnit(int playerID)
    {
        Debug.Log("Creating player unit with ID: " + playerID + " and isLocalPlayer: "+isLocalPlayer);
        GC.registerPlayerNetID(playerID);
        Debug.Log("(PM) Registered Players: " + GC.playerNetIDs.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < GC.playerNetIDs.Count; i++)
        {
            //Debug.Log(GC.playerNetIDs[i]);
            if(GC.playerNetIDs[i]==playerID)
            {
                playerUnitID = i;
                Debug.Log(playerID+" player's unitID is "+i);
            }
        }
        GameObject prefab = GC.players[playerUnitID];
        GameObject playerUnit = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, prefab.transform.position, prefab.transform.rotation);
        NetworkServer.Spawn(playerUnit);

        //Update the same in GC
        GC.registerPlayer1(playerUnit,(int)playerUnitID);
    }






}
```

Comment: Can't say I'm familiar with the command attribute but you might try returning from one of the methods if not local player as shown in unity docs https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.CommandAttribute.html